# React Native Height Adjustment

Tags: react-native

I just started and installed react-native. After installing, I wrote some codes from skeleton codes, but height is always 667. 
Even View height is only 300, AppContainer height is 667, View height is more than 667, it cuts contents not expanding height.
Could you help me to figure out this?

```
            /**
     * Sample React Native App
     * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
     * @flow
     */

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View
    } from 'react-native';

    export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              To get started, edit index.ios.js
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
              Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: Can you maybe post the relevant code and/or a screenshot of the result?

Comment: I posted skeleton codes which makes same issue